# How to "parse" js twice?

Tags: javascript, parsing

The following Code should output:

txt1txt2txt3...

```
var result =''; 
var help='';
var a_1 = "txt1";
var a_2 = "txt2";
...

for (i=1;i<=100;i++)
{
    help = 'a_' + i;           // This line should be "parsed twice" !
    result  = result + help;
    document.write(result);

}
```

Of course, I can avoid this by using the **if-, or case-function** for each "a_ i", 
but this would make my js file very big.

**So is there a way to parse this "help line" twice with js?**

I asume, I could do it with including one js file in another, but I dont like this way?

**No PHP** , because the code should work clientside

Comment: why don't you store them in an array?

Comment: Seems like a job for [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Comment: thx, the array storage should do the job

Comment: I would prefer restructuring (like @DanielA.White suggested) sooooo much over `eval`!

Comment: @mishik eval is evil.

Comment: @DanielA.White I know :)

Comment: @mishik, I do have user input, so i asume eval() would be dangerous

Comment: Well, there's no user input in `"a_" + i`, so I would guess that you are safe there.

Comment: @mishik sry, this is just a sample, my implementation is different

Comment: `eval()` isn't evil, and it's not automatically dangerous just because there's user input on the page. It's just almost always the wrong tool for the job. In this case an array is the obvious solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript dynamic variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Better to use an **array**.
2. `eval()`  is the function for "double parsing"  (but **could** be really dangerous !)